# VC++ MFC application cant log mouse numerical coordinates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Im new to MFC and Im trying to create a quick application on windows to simulate a hardware/computer peripheral that I will later integrate with, when its available,however the hardware will send screen x & y coordinates.

I created a MFC application that captures mouse events & on mouse move event.

I'm able to capture the mouse move events, however the log does NOT show a numerical value for X & Y and instead outputs .cpp file path for X's value & and nothing for Y, strange?

**See code snippet below:**

```
  void CRingExampleView::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    /*
    I also tried declaring a new point POINT p and passing that to GetCursorPos(&p), but still now numerical output
    */
    if (GetCursorPos(&point))
    {

        TRACE("X:", point.x);
        TRACE("Y:", point.y);

    }

    CScrollView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

        CScrollView::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
    }//end function
```

See the screenshot for log and the app:

[image]

How can I output the numerical x & y values?

Thanks

Comment: "New" to MFC???  MFC is already at least a decade obsolete :(  Is there any chance you could use a *different* technology?  Or must you (for whatever reason) use MFC?

Comment: If you want to use the `TRACE` macro, you should consider reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/mfc-debugging-techniques#BKMK_The_TRACE_macro).

Comment: @paulsm4: Based on what information did you conclude, that MFC were obsolete? It isn't. It is still officially supported by Microsoft, and it is the only officially supported C++ framework for desktop application development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your TRACE statement needs a format string.

EXAMPLE:

```
 TRACE(_T("X: %d"), point.x);
```

You can read more here:

[MFC Debugging Techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx52ww7.aspx)